# Is it mandatory to use position property while styling webpages?

Tags: html, css

While applying css I am getting the desired result without the use of the position property i.e:-

```
position:relative; or
position:absolute; etc...
```

But, I am a bit worried - is this the right way?

I mean, is applying position property for styling with css considered a good practice?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether it is best to style the position property depends on your specific situation. If you have need to take elements out of the flow of the page, then you may want to use it.

But **no**, the `position` property is definitely not mandatory.

If you have styled your page without using `position` - and your satisfied that it is fully functional, there's nothing wrong with that.

[Read about positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) to properly understand when to and why we change it from the default.

Answer (score 2):

No. For the vast majority of things, `position: static` (the default) is fine.

Other positioning schemes should be used with a light touch. You can achieve some very powerful effects with them, but for most purposes such things are not needed, and used improperly they can create very fragile layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Going by the CSS tutorial here:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

They are good if you wish to affect the positioning of the image, for example if you need to move it slightly or position it next to another image.

more reading can be found here with examples:
http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/position.html

Personally I always position them, but I do not think it matters

Comment: Generally speaking, if you need to move something slightly, you are better off using a margin.

Answer (score 0):

Every element is `static` positioned by default

You cannot use `z-index:property` without the `position` property

You will not get the desired effect for `z-index`,if you are not specifying any of the position properties(`relative`,`absolute`,`fixed`)

`left/right/top/bottom/z-index` have no effect on a `static` positioned element.

NOTE:Just spend a few minutes here too [position](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/)